# Masonry item lower opacity instead of hiding

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I know that default *Masonry* behaviour is to hide item, when item is in active (other category is chosen), but in my code it lowers opacity to 0.25 instead of hiding and all other items regrouping: http://veritaswp.excellence.lt/en/photo-gallery/

There is my CSS code:

```
.project.inactive {
  opacity: .25 !important;
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

I have tried instead of `opacity` parameter write `display: none`, but *masonry* item still take space (because *masonry* items are with `position: absolute`, I guess).

How can I solve this problem? How to hide *masonry* item with all items regrouping, instead of lowering it's `opacity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: none` on the items you want to hide first and then
call masonry again on your container like so:

```
$(".masonry").masonry();
```

Or

```
$(".masonry").masonry("layout");
```

That is if you're using jQuery. If you're using plain JavaScript, just do the same thing.

That way with `display:none` your unwanted items will be removed from the flow and calling layout will re-order your remaining items accordingly.

**EDIT** [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpwRwm)

Comment: Glad I could help!